# C++: Protected Class Constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, base-class

If a class is always going to be inherited, does it make sense to make the constructor `protected`?

```
class Base
{
protected:
    Base();
};

class Child : protected Base
{
public:
    Child() : Base();
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: There's no need to explicitly initialize the `Base`, by the way.

Comment: @GMan This is not an accurate example of what I am doing. I just did as little code as I could, while still getting my point across.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That only makes sense if you don't want clients to create instances of `Base`, rather you intend it to be base-class of some [derived] classes, and/or intend it to be used by friends of `Base` (see example below). Remember `protected` functions (and constructors) can only be invoked from derived classes and `friend` classes.

```
class Sample;
class Base
{
    friend class Sample;
protected:
    Base() {}
};

class Sample
{
 public:
   Sample()
   {
      //invoking protected constructor
      Base *p = new Base();
   }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

If it's always going to be a base (a "mixin"), yes. Keep in mind a class with pure virtual functions will always be a base, but you won't need to do this since it cannot be instantiated anyway.

Also, give it either [a public virtual destructor or a protected non-virtual destructor](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm).

Comment: Just realized that a protected non-virtual destructor would be the right fix for some classes I've written that are used polymorphically but never deleted polymorphically.  I never could get rid of the compiler warning suggesting a virtual destructor, but this might just do it.

Comment: If this matters, at this time, I don't plan on having any pure virtual functions.

Comment: @Jay: So then if it doesn't make sense for the class to be used as anything but a base, make a protected constructor.

Comment: @Jay: No problem. Just don't fall into the trap of confusing "It shouldn't be used without being a base." with "I'll never use it without it being a base."; the latter doesn't imply the former.